# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer ( python 3.4 version)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a video file and getting error as below.

```
$ /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    img_aug = process_frame(img)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/lane.py", line 615, in process_frame
    output = create_output_frame(offcenter, pts, img_undist_, fps, curvature, curve_direction, binary_sub)

  File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/lane.py", line 467, in create_output_frame
    whole_frame = np.zeros((h*2.5,w*2.34, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Please provide the code in which the error occures.

Comment: Your mistake on the line `whole_frame = np.zeros((h*2.5,w*2.34, 3), dtype=np.uint8)` is that you try to set floating point numbers as dimensions of your array. Array dimensions are integers.

Comment: How can I retain the floating value?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Like assigning them to variables and maintaining them until your program finishes?

Comment: I donot want the values..2.5 and 2.34 to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Below line is reason for error.

```
np.zeros((h*2.5,w*2.34, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

[`np.zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) expects dimensions as integers, while `h*2.5` and `w*2.34` evaluates as `float`. If you wish you can cast arguments to integer using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: How can I retain the floating value.

Comment: Simply, assign those values to new variable and use when you need them or recalculate it.

Comment: It creates frame to hold an image

Comment: Is there a way to make 'whole_frame' take floating values?

Comment: Plz help with the syntax as I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution to it..I initially tried replacing floating values to 3 and 2 for 3.5 and 3.24 respectively.But got error as these values reduce the total frame dimension.Then changed it to 
np.zeros((h*3,w*3,3), dtype=np.uint8) and it works..!!